# C Linked list inserting element in a sorted way

Tags: c, sorting, insert, linked-list

Hey I need to insert an element into linked list in a sorted way. Each element has isbn  which I need the linked list to be sorted with.It kind of works because it inserts the smallest element at the head but that's it the rest seems to be sorted in random way.
Here is my code

```
void insertABook(linkedlist *root, linkedlist *newbook)
{ 
    if ((root==NULL) && (root->ptr==NULL))
    {
        root->ptr=newbook;
    }
    else
    {
        linkedlist *next = root;
        while((next->ptr != NULL) && (next->isbn < newbook->isbn))
        {
            next = next->ptr;
        }
        newbook->ptr=next->ptr;
        next->ptr=newbook;
    }
}
```

The root parameter is dummy node(NULL) and the newbook parameter is new element to be inserted. I add elements one by one using this method.

Comment: In `(next->isbn < newbook->isbn)` you are not comparing the ISBNs but the string pointers. Use `(strcmp(next->isbn, newbook->isbn) < 0)`. I know the ISBN is a string not a number because the last char can be an X.

Comment: nevermind I've found the solution the problem was i was comparing next->isbn number instead of next->ptr->isbn

Comment: `if ((root==NULL) && (root->ptr==NULL))` --> `if ((root!=NULL) && (root->ptr==NULL))` ??

Answer (score 1):

The Parameter root is a value that is an address stored in the root.
I guess your code.

```
    linkedlist *root = NULL, *newbook;
    while (...) {   // or for( , , )
        newbook = malloc(sizeof(linkedlist));
        // edit newbook
        insertABook(root, newbook);
              :
              :
```

There is at least 3 way.
1. insertABook() return linkedlist* to store the root.

```
        root = insertABook(root, newbook);
```

2. change root as linkedlist**. I guess this is the answer what you want.

```
void insertABook(linkedlist **root, linkedlist *newbook) {
    if (*root==NULL) {
        *root=newbook;
    }
    else {  // insert or append
        linkedlist  *next = *root;
            :
            :
```

caller

```
        insertABook(&root, newbook);
```

&root is an address of root.

3. root is global within the source file.

   ```
   static linkedlist   *root = NULL;
   ```